# Overflow in visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

I have a game server, and problem on error overflow 6.

Debug:

```
If Spell(spellnum).END > 0 Then
    TempPlayer(Index).END = GetPlayerStat(Index, Endurance)
    SetPlayerStat Index, Endurance, GetPlayerStat(Index, Endurance) + Spell(spellnum).END
    SendStats Index
End If
```

DEBUG highlighted:

```
    TempPlayer(Index).END = GetPlayerStat(Index, Endurance)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what kind of your return on line:

> GetPlayerStat(Index, Endurance)

You can check the type of return and the allocation? Usually when I have problems with overflow is by trying to put a number like "long" (high value) in a variable of type "integer" or "single" for example.